# Qt отследить бездействие пользователя

Tags: linux, qt, xubuntu

Необходимо по бездействию пользователя выходить из системы. Решил отслеживать перемещения мыши. Т.е. если мышка какое-то время не двигается, то выполнить какую-то функцию выхода:

```
this->setMouseTracking(true);

void MainWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
        {
            QTimer *mousetimer = new QTimer(this);
            connect(mousetimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(on_logoutPushButton_clicked()));
            mousetimer->start(5000);
        }
    }

void MainWindow::on_logoutPushButton_clicked()
{

    this->close();
    newauth = new AuthDialog;
    newauth->show();
}
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Поясните в чем проблема.

Comment: То есть, каждый раз, когда пользователь дергнет мышку, вы создаете новый таймер?

Comment: ну если дергает мышку то таймер обнуляем. Если прошло 5 сек. то выходим. Или как лучше? На данный момент не работает.

Comment: по мышке не достоверно получится, а если стол дрогнул и мыша пошевелилась, ну или не пользуют мышу по долгу т.к. данные вводят с клавиатуры. Мне представляется что нужно вести лог системы, и допустим если в течении 10 минут в системе нет событий , то тогда выход

Comment: Нужно знать бездействие на уровне всей системы, или только бездействие в данном приложении? То есть если пользователь свернул программу и активно работает в другой, эта программа никаких событий получать не будет - это считается бездействием? Если все-таки на уровне всей системы, то тут надо уже обращаться к системным ресурсам и они в каждой системе свои. У Вас какая?

Comment: Linux (xubuntu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На linux/X11 узнавать о времени бездействия пользователя можно через API хранителя экрана (screensaver).

На машине разработки установите `libxss-dev`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxss-dev
```

В файл `.pro` добавьте

```
LIBS += -lX11 -lXss
```

В новом проекте по умолчанию код выглядит следующим образом:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void checkIdle();

private:
    void logout();

    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QTimer>
#include <X11/extensions/scrnsaver.h>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    checkIdle(); // запускаем отслеживание
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::checkIdle()
// отслеживание периода бездействия пользователя
{
    static Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    if (display == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    static XScreenSaverInfo *info = XScreenSaverAllocInfo();
    XScreenSaverQueryInfo(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), info);

    const int targetIdleMs = 5 * 1000;   // целевое время бездействия в миллисекундах
    const int actualIdleMs = info->idle; // фактическое время бездействия в мс
    if (actualIdleMs < targetIdleMs) {
        // ждем оставшееся время до целевого и потом снова проверяем
        QTimer::singleShot(targetIdleMs - actualIdleMs, this, SLOT(checkIdle()));
    } else {
        // целевое время достигнуто
        logout();
    }
}

void MainWindow::logout()
// желаемые действия при бездействии пользователя
{
    close();
}
```

Для пояснения. Добавлены две функции

```
private slots:
    void checkIdle();
private:
    void logout();
```

В `.cpp` добавлены

```
#include <QTimer>
#include <X11/extensions/scrnsaver.h>
```

Из конструктора вызываем `checkIdle()`. В ней константой `targetIdleMs` задаем целевое время бездействия, сравниваем с фактическим и по таймеру ждем до следующей проверки. При очередной проверке если необходимый период не образовался, опять ждем; иначе вызываем `logout()`, которая в данном случае закрывает программу.

Comment: При каждом повторном вызове `XOpenDisplay()` будет возвращать указатель на закешировнную в Xlib информацию? (просто в [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xopendisplay) говорится только о том, что этот вызвов устанавливает соединение с сервером и ни слова об его повторном использовании)